# Como buscar uma lista de classes contidas em uma Biblioteca de classes C# utilizando Mono com C++

Tags: c#, dll, mono

Estou utilizando **C#** para script através do projeto **Mono** com **C++**. Estou tentando buscar uma lista de todas as classes contidas em uma **DLL** feita em um projeto **C#** (que é um projeto de Biblioteca de classes).
 Mas não estou encontrando uma solução. Estou pesquisando a documentação mas a documentação é horrível.

Estive pesquisando muito, mas nada de uma solução....
 A baixo uma exemplo de classes contida na **DLL**.

```
using System;

namespace Nodes
{
    public class BaseNode
    {
        public string m_Name = "Unamed";
        public string m_Description = "None";
        public int m_Id = -1;

        public void SetName(string newName) { m_Name = newName; }
        public string GetName() { return m_Name; }

        public void SetDescription(string newDescription) { m_Description = newDescription; }
        public string GetDescription() { return m_Description; }

        public void SetId(int newId) { m_Id = newId; }
        public int GetId() { return m_Id; }
    }
}
```

E o código que está incompleto.

```
mono_set_dirs("C:\\Program Files\\Mono\\lib", "C:\\Program Files\\Mono\\etc");
mono_config_parse(nullptr);

MonoDomain* domain = mono_init_version("MonoApplycation", "v4.0.30319");
MonoAssembly* assembly = mono_domain_assembly_open(domain, (absPath(getExecutablePath()) + "\\..\\Debug\\MyDLL.dll").c_str());

if (!assembly) {
    std::cout << "Error, 'assembly' is null\n";
}
else {
    MonoImage* image = mono_assembly_get_image(assembly);
    // Carregar todoas as classes....
}
```

Comment: tenta essas ferramentas http://www.dependencywalker.com/ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/756as972%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: O nome de classes é variável de compilador para compilador. Se você fez a API em C++, recomendo que a transforme em uma de C